# How to change the size of the resolution based on division

Tags: python, image-processing

I would like to change the resolution of the image (nHeight = Height of the picture) and make it divisible to 8. I am using the below python code. Can anyone help me for this?

```
  if (nHeight%8 != 0):
            try:
                while (nHeight%8 == 0):
                    nHeight = nHeight +1
                    print(nHeight%8)
            except:
                pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
while n_height % 8 != 0:
        n_height += 1
```

If `n_height` is, let's say 17, before running the above block, then afterwards it would be 24.

The `if` block is not necessary, because the `while` won't execute if your resolution size is already divisible by 8.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler form that **doesn't use loops** or *try* /*except* blocks, but math operations:

```py
if nHeight % 8:
    nHeight = nHeight // 8 * 8 + 8
print(nHeight)
```

The secret is the `n // 8` which is called *floor division* ([[Python 2.Docs]: Binary arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)).
You could also use regular division (on *Python 2*)... well assuming that *nHeight* is an integer - which kind of makes sense if the resolution is expressed in pixels.

- Integer division returns the quotient
- That is then multiplied by *8* to get the **highest *8*** multiple, **less than** our number
- Finally, added another *8* to get the **lowest *8*** multiple, **greater than** our number

The whole expression is equivalent to `nHeight = (nHeight // 8 + (1 if nHeight % 8 else 0)) * 8`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a bug: `while (nHeight%8 == 0)` needs to be `while (nHeight%8 != 0)`. But it doesn't matter, because what you want to accomplish is easy with a simple expression that eliminates the `while` loop and `if` testing altogether:

```
nHeight = ((nHeight + 7) // 8) * 8
```

This works for any positive number. `//` is integer division, throwing away the remainder. By adding 7 before dividing, you don't change the result if it's already divisible by 8 but you bump the division result by 1 if it wasn't; multiplying by 8 again compensates for the division and makes it obvious the result will be divisible by 8.

P.S. it's quite unusual to see Hungarian notation in Python, it goes against the [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines.